# Хранение дополнительных данных в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, сессия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Laravel хранить данные о пользователе после его авторизации?

К примеру, есть таблица users и в ней только базовая информация о пользователе (использовать данные после авторизации из таблицы я могу - `$user = Auth::user();`), так же есть таблица к примеру `options`, которая хранит данные о настроенном пользователем интерфейсе веб приложения.
 Так вот, после авторизации (реализована через `middleware`) как единожды подгрузить дополнительные данные о пользователе и каким образом после их передавать по мере действий клиента и перезагрузки страницы (соответственно переходы между контроллерами). Есть ли какой-то специальный механизм в `Laravel` или использовать обычные `session` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сделайте модель для опций, например UserOptions
2. Добавьте в модель User связь с опциями:

   ```
   class User extends Authenticatable {
   //...
       public function options () {
           return $this->hasOne('App\UserOptions');
       }
   //...
   }
   ```
3. В шаблонах после $user = Auth::user(); можете теперь использовать $user->options

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал!